# How to set up the ClosureTable component with Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, package

this component here ...

https://github.com/franzose/ClosureTable

looks very promising, I wanted to give it a try, but couldn't figure out how to install it. Some sparse instructions are given on the project page, but they seem both outdated and incomplete.

The composer.json part is clear, and upon

```
composer update
```

I got the packet downloaded to Laravel's vendor subdirectory.

Then the docs instruct to add to app/config/app.config

```
'providers' => array(
        // ...
        'Franzose\ClosureTable\ClosureTableServiceProvider',
    ),
```

I guess, this is outdated and very likely incomplete, there is a similar file in config/app.php, but it's internal structure looks completely different. Finally I found some posts about severe troubles installing custom packages because of problems with autoloading.

Would anyone pleas have a look at this package and give me instructions how I need to install it?

Thanks very much,

Armin.

Comment: which version of laravel are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the package without any issue following the steps:

1. On your project directory `run composer franzose/closure-table": "4.`
2. Go to `config/app.php` on `'providers' => array` add:

   ```
   Franzose\ClosureTable\ClosureTableServiceProvider::class,

    //or

   'Franzose\ClosureTable\ClosureTableServiceProvider',
   ```

Comment: I guess what you mean is:

composer require franzose/closure.table "5.0"

(since, like I said in my question, I have Laravel 5.4.28). You seem to have Laravel 4! The config/app.php is, however, a Laravel 5 directory name. How do these informations go togehter?

Comment: Leo,
thanks for your answer, it proofed correct. Somehow somewhere my Laravel project has suffered some damage, it seems. While I cannot find the problem, I was able to install ClosureTable in a fresh laravel project.
Unfortunately I didn't get very far though, the next kaboom happened when ClosureTable tried to initialize the databases: it's foreign key constraints seem to be incompatible with Microsoft SQL server. I post a separate question, because it is a separate issue. In case you are interested, see here: https://github.com/franzose/ClosureTable/issues/192